# IIS 10.0 & ASP.NET Core Web API : route issue

Tags: .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, hosting, windows-server

I deployed my APS.NET Core Web API application to a Windows server which has IIS 10.0 installed.

Everything works fine, but my route looks a bit strange.

This is screenshot from my VS:

[image]

As you can see this route should be `www.something.com/api/b2c/articles`

But in fact to make my API work, I need to add `/api/api` twice which is little bit strange to me.

Because at the beginning I tried this route from postman:

```
www.something.com/api/b2c/articles
```

and it said 404 not found..

Somehow I added `/api/api` and it worked..

Example of working route:

```
www.something.com/api/api/b2c/articles
```

How is this possible ?

What I need to do, where should I look at ? I am not familiar with IIS and this is a bit pain for me..

EL B2B is frontend application

[image]

On the image above ELB2B is new website which contains path to frontend dist folder.

Within same website I added new application which is actually my ASP.NET Core Web API app.

Maybe I should add ASP.NET Core Web API app separately as a new website or ?

Really any kind of help would be awesome!

Comment: Well, the virtual app is called "api", and your route also specifies `/api` in the beginning - so you end up with `/api/api` ..... how to solve it? Just changed your route attribute to: `Route("/b2c/articles")` and the the virtual app add a single `/api` before that ....

Comment: @marc_s Appreciate your help! Thanks a lot! Well, since there is a lot of endpoint in my app that are using /api in the beginning of the route I wouldn't like to change anything in my app. What are you proposing to do on server to avoid this? Maybe I could create separately new website which would point only to api ? And if I delete virtual app from my current website everything might work as expected?

Comment: Look at the basic and advanced settings of your Virtual Application in IIS - I'm not intimately familiar with that, but maybe there's a way to tell IIS to avoid using the name of the virtual application as part of the URL ......

Comment: virtual directory `api` here is required to differ from the parent website. when the endpoint `www.something.com/api` means it would go to the sub virtual directory to match the request. maybe you can rename the virtual directory name?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, do you get a solution/workaround for this?